# How can I start to implement a serial port control using MVVM Model?

Tags: c#, wpf, design-patterns, mvvm

I'm starting to creat this project using MVVM Model. But I have no idea how can I implementing it using a toolbar.

I need a little of help. This is the site web which I'm watching:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.aspx

I think the last one would be the model, I'm not sure if I'm doing fine:

```
public class Port : INotifyPropertyChanged, IDataErrorInfo
{
    private SerialPort _serialPort;

    public Port()
    {
        _serialPort = new SerialPort();
    }

    public string PortName
    {
        get { return _serialPort.PortName; }
        set
        {
            _serialPort.PortName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("PortName");
        }
    }

    public int BaudRate
    {
        get { return _serialPort.BaudRate; }
        set
        {
            _serialPort.BaudRate = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("BaudRate");
        }
    }

    public Parity Parity
    {
        get { return _serialPort.Parity; }
        set
        {
            _serialPort.Parity = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Parity");
        }
    }

    public int DataBits
    {
        get { return _serialPort.DataBits; }
        set
        {
            _serialPort.DataBits = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("PortDataBits");
        }
    }

    public StopBits StopBits
    {
        get { return _serialPort.StopBits; }
        set
        {
            _serialPort.StopBits = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("PortStopBits");
        }
    }

    public Handshake Handshake
    {
        get { return _serialPort.Handshake; }
        set
        {
            _serialPort.Handshake = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("PortHandshake");
        }
    }

    public string[] AvailablePortNames
    {
        get { return SerialPort.GetPortNames(); }
    }

    #region IDataErrorInfo Members

    string IDataErrorInfo.Error { get { return null; } }

    string IDataErrorInfo.this[string propertyName]
    {
        get { return this.GetValidationError(propertyName); }
    }
```

The program consists that the user must set and configure and open it. I need a little of help about how can I implement it using this model. Thanks a lot.

[image]

Comment: Be sure the names passed in to OnPropertyChanged match the property names

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need a ViewModel that contains 1 SerialPort and a few Lists for baudrates, parity-options etc.

You can then use a ComboBox, bind the ItemsSource to the list and the SelectedItem to a SerialPort property.